# How to insert processed spark stream into kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

am trying to insert spark stream into kafka after being processed using the below snippet

```
query = ds1 \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .writeStream\
    .foreachBatch(do_something) \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("topic","topic-name") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "borkers-IPs") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/location") \
    .start()
```

but it seems it's inserting the original stream not the processed one.

Comment: borkers ...brokers?

Comment: not aware that foreachbatch works this way - that is for arbitrary non-standard sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of foreachBatch has no effect here as you can see. Spark will not generate an error, it will just be like into the void.

> Quote from the manuals:
>
> Structured Streaming APIs provide two ways to write the output of a
> streaming query to data sources that do not have an existing streaming
> sink: foreachBatch() and foreach().

This excellent read is what you are looking for.

https://aseigneurin.github.io/2018/08/14/kafka-tutorial-8-spark-structured-streaming.html